# App fails to launch on simulator for some users

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

We are generating an App version for our QA testers to try on their simulators. For most of them it works fine, but we have two users the App is crashing on startup. By checking the Console logs we have this issue with launchd.

```
error   12:22:42.120557+0200    SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x17bbe0440; app<com.package.of.the.app((null))>:<invalid>> with error: <NSError: 0x60000146b930; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; "Launch failed."> {
NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x60000146bed0; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 1> {
    NSLocalizedDescription = Launchd job spawn failed;
};
```

}

Has anyone encountered this issue? We have tried to restart the simulator, clean Derived Data, restart the Mac and the simulator, try with other Apps and simulators, generate the App from another computer and nothing works.
Both the Mac that are generating the .app and the tester Macs are M2

Comment: Similar error for me:
Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x17f4c4000; app<com.ans-soft.app((null))>:<invalid>> with error: <NSError: 0x6000023e2e80; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; "Launch failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x60000230d590; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 153> {
        NSLocalizedDescription = Launchd job spawn failed;
    };
}

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
In some of our Macs, extended attribute com.apple.quarantine was added to the App so it couldn't run.

Try running the following command on your testing Mac:

`xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine ./XXXX.app`